# Cp command on CentOs8 Stream sometimes give error hosts id down but copy files

Tags: file, copy, filesystems, cp, centos8

I have mounted windows files cifs in mnt. I try copy files VIA cp command sometimes i get error hosts is down but files are copied correctly. Why ?

I try mount option, session limit, SSH ,users,version cifs